# Powershell cmdlet to gracefully shutdown azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am having questions around the "Stop-AzureRmVm" PowerShell cmdlet. Does the cmdlet power crash the virtual machines? I have few SharePoint and SQL servers used in our non-production environment. I have powershell scripts that do a scheduled stop and start of these virtual machines.

I am worried if the "Stop-AzureRmVm" PowerShell cmdlet power crashes the virtual machines, as I need the servers to gracefully shutdown.

OR do we have any PowerShell cmdlet that gracefully shuts down the Azure virtual machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are not sending the `-force` parameter, Azure will attempt to gracefully shutdown the guest OS before stopping.  If that doesn't work, the `-force` parameter is akin to "pulling the plug".

Answer (score 2):

Dont worry, the command `Stop-AzureRmVm` will gracefully shut down the VM.

If you catch the request of the `Stop-AzureRmVm` and the `Stop` option of the VM in the portal, you will find essentially they all call the [`Virtual Machines - Deallocate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/deallocate) REST API, it means if you use the powershell command, it is no difference with that in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old question, but Ken W's accepted answer here is not accurate.  The *-Force* parameter only prevents a Yes/No prompt when running the cmdlet (this is useful for when running in an automated script which cannot accept user input).  Either way, running Stop-AzureRmVm will always attempt a graceful shutdown.

The newer 'Az' version of this cmdlet (Stop-AzVM) does have a *-SkipShutdown* option which will skip any attempt at a graceful shutdown, and will immediately deallocate the VM.  More details can be found in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/stop-azvm